# Overwriting tap event with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a lot of:

```
$('#element').on('tap', function(){
    // some code ..
})
```

I searched many questions about the `tap` event problem firing twice, and I solved my problem using `e.preventDefault()`, now I have a lot of:

```
$('#element').on('tap', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // some code ..
})
```

---

Ok, but as I said, I have many of these calls and I don't like much to write every time `e.preventDefault()`, then I typed `$.fn.tap` on chrome's console and it showed me:

```
function (a){return a?this.bind(c,a):this.trigger(c)}
```

I tried to overwrite it this way:

```
$.fn.tap = function (a) {
    a.preventDefault(); 
    return a?this.bind(c,a):this.trigger(c)
}
```

But it didn't worked as it did in the previous `e.preventDefault()`.

I'm not seeing anything obvious and I'm out of ideas for this.

Any help or idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$.fn.tap` creates a function called as `$('#element').tap()`, it does not create an event

Comment: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}

Comment: try returning false. if you fire on function in jqyer

Comment: @adeneo. Seeing @BG101 answer I think I got the idea, but.. then, how to overwrite the `.on('tap', func..`? Or is it only possible to overwrite the `.tap(func..` ?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes - nope, you can change jQuery's event proccessing directly, I'll post something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the cool features of jQuery (I usually don't use 'jQuery' and 'cool' in a single sentence) is that it lets you specify custom behaviour for events, using the `$.event.special` object.

There is [very little documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/#add-function-handleobj) on the subject, so a little example would be in order.
A working fiddle using the `click` event (*as this was more convenient for me to write on my laptop*) [can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/ose51t4c/)

Translated to your request to have *all* `tap` events have `e.preventDefault()` invoked before the actual handler, would look like:

```
$.event.special.tap.add = function(options) {
  var handler = options.handler;

  options.handler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    return handler.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}
```

What this code does (should do, as I haven't actually tested the `tap` version above) is telling jQuery that you want a special treatment for the `tab` event, more particularly you want to provide a 'wrapping handler' which does nothing more than call `e.preventDefault()` before calling the provided event handler.

*UPDATE: prevented the default `tap`-settings from being overwritten, for future visitors*

---

*NOTE:* Before you make any attempt on changing the default behaviour of things, you should ask yourself why the defaults don't work for you. Mostly because changing default (=expected) behaviour will upset your future self (or worse, another person) while maintaining your code and adding features.

In order to create a maintainable (and predictable) flow in your code the suggested solution to create a special case function (`$.fn.tap`) is in fact a very viable solution, as it does not interfere with the default (=expected) behaviour of things.

From the links I provided you should also be able to create your own event type (e.g. `tapOnly`) and make it more obvious there is some custom work involved. Then again, both of these solutions will require you to change your event bindings, which is what you are trying to prevent.

Comment: Man, this is awesome!!.. I just changed your code to `$.event.special.tap.add = function(){...` because the `Object {tapholdThreshold: 750, emitTapOnTaphold: true}` were been replaced and the `tap` event failed, but now it is working perfectly!

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `special`. well deserved bounty. +1

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the code sample to reflect your suggestion @WashingtonGuedes, which does in fact prevent the other values from being overwritten.

Answer (score 10):

This is how you can create your `$.fn.tap`:-

```
$.fn.tap = function(f) {
  $(this).on('tap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    f();
  });
  return this;
};

//usage
$('.selector').tap(function() {
  alert('foo bar')
})
```

> **@Washington Guedes** - overwrite the default tap-event to always use e.preventDefault()
>   rather than changing from $(element).on('tap', function(){}) to
>   $(element).tap(function(){})

You could add a delegate event to `body` for `tap`, without specifying a target. This will then fire for all `tap` events on the body, which you can then check if the target has its own `tap` event, so you can then `e.preventDefault();`.

**NOTE**: This will not work for delegated `tap` events as shown.

```js
// global tap handler
$('body').on('tap', function(e) {
  if ($._data(e.target, "events").tap)
    e.preventDefault();
});

// tap event
$('a.tap').on('tap', function(e) {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
});

// delegated tap event
$('body').on('tap', 'a.delegate', function(e) {
  $(this).css('color', 'green');
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<a class="tap" href="www.google.co.uk">tap event, prevented.</a>
<a class="delegate" href="www.google.co.uk">delegate tap event, not prevented.</a>
<a href="www.google.co.uk">no tap event, not prevented</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I knew can be a bad idea but I've just tested this in Chrome

```
$('*').on('tap',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#element').on('tap', function(){
    // some code ..
});
```

and  if you don't need this for all elements:

```
$('*').not('#aCertainElement').on('tap',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in which `e.preventDefault()` would work on some cases, but not on others. It showed no errors, and using `try-catch` was not displaying the `catch alert`. Adding `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` did the trick, in case it helps anyone